# Unable to Install magento 1.7 on godaddy hosted account

Tags: magento-1.7

I have followed all the links related to this but I am not able to install.
I am installing on the godadday hosted account.
On the first installation page I am getting "No Input file specified".
Can u pls specify step by step procedure to install.

Comment: Instructions here will be probably the same, it would be better to list what you have done / tried, other issues you have noticed,... so we can start off from there.

Comment: I have added RewriteBase /    ,Options -MultiViews in htaccess file. Created php5.ini and added cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1

Answer (score 2):

This video has a step by step overview on how to set it up:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YicBzxnrnOM

Your particular problem is well-known and has been documented in a few places including the Magento Wiki:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/error/no_input_file_specified

From the article:

> add this to your .htaccess file
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
> RewriteRule ^.+.php$ /bogusfile
> ```
>
> Then try to reload your setup page.
>
> If you do not have Magento setup in the root of your server, make sure
>   to add the following to your .htaccess file.
>
> ```
> RewriteBase /yourbasepath/
> ```
>
> Once that is verified, there are a couple things you can do to fix
>   this, but we’ll start with the one that usually works.
>
> In your web root directory, there should be a file called php.ini.
>   Rename this to php5.ini.
>
> If there is no php5.ini file. Create the file and upload it to your
>   root directory.
>
> If that doesn’t work, add the following to the end of your newly
>   renamed php5.ini file:
>
> ```
> cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
> ```
>
> And if you’re still getting the error, add the following to the top of
>   your .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> Options -MultiViews
> ```
>
> The first one usually does the trick. If you don’t see this file in
>   there, then create a blank php5.ini file add add the line listed on
>   the second suggestion.
>
> If all of the above has not worked, **KEEP your changes, wait exactly 24
>   hours.** Go back to youraddress.tld/downloader and try again. You may
>   just be cached and for some reason it takes a bit longer then I was
>   used to. Keep your chin up!
>
> **If nothing above worked, call GoDaddy up and have them either rename
>   this for you, or make sure you’re on PHP 5.**